# Prime inert in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is also inert in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ contains at least $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, and in fact since $\alpha$ is integral and generates $K$ we have $[\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$ is finite. If I have a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ which is inert in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, can I conclude that $p$ is also inert in $\mathcal{O}_K$?

In this specific instance, I have $\alpha = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^{-1}$, and $p=5$. Then $5$ is inert in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ since

$$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta + \zeta^{-1}]/(5)\mathbb{Z}[\zeta + \zeta^{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(p, 5) = \mathbb{F}_5[x]/(\overline{p})$$

where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, and $\overline{p}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5$. I want to conclude (if possible) that $(5)$ is inert in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^{-1})}$. (In fact, in this case is the ring of integers equal to $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta + \zeta^{-1}]$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true by Dedekind-Kummer. Let $ f \in \mathbf Z[X] $ be the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha $, so that $ p $ being inert in $ \mathbf Z[\alpha] $ is equivalent to $ f $ being irreducible mod $ p $. But then, $ p $ does not divide the discriminant of $ f $, which means it also does not divide the index $ [\mathcal O_K : \mathbf Z[\alpha]] $, i.e the conductor of the order $ \mathbf Z[\alpha] $. Therefore, the way $ p $ splits in $ \mathbf Z[\alpha] $ is equivalent to the way it splits in $ \mathcal O_K $.